# How to separate yaml.dump key:value pair by a new line?

Tags: python, yaml

I am trying to make yaml dump each key:value pair on a separate line. Is there a native option to do that? I have tried line_break but couldn't get it to work.

Here is a code example:

```
import yaml

def test_yaml_dump():

    obj = {'key0': 1, 'key1': 2}

    with open('test.yaml', 'w') as tmpf:
        yaml.dump(obj, tmpf, line_break=0)
```

The output is:

```
{key0: 1, key1: 2}
```

I want it to be:

```
{key0: 1, 
key1: 2}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the argument `default_flow_style=False` to dump then the output will be:

```
key1: 2
key0: 1
```

(the so called block style). That is the much more readable way of dumping Python dicts to YAML mappings. In `ruamel.yaml` this is the default when using `ruamel.yaml.round_trip_dump()`.

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml as yaml

obj = dict(key0=1, key1=2)
yaml.round_trip_dump(obj, sys.stdout)
```